# How safe it is to use third party FRP frameworks for long running project knowing that swift is constantly being changed?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

**Background:**

I need to start working on project which we are hoping to maintain it for long time (Basically reusable components which will be reused in multiple projects). I was exploring the Reactive Programming and the benefits Reactive Programming brings to the table is way to high to ignore it.

I started exploring various FRP frameworks available and `RxSwift`, `ReactiveCocoa` were few such examples. But looking at the community support and swift implementation, RxSwift was obviously the choice.

Now `RxSwift4` came with some breaking changes as `RxSwift3` wasn't compatible with `Swift4`. Now community did a great job to bridge the changes smooth, though but things like `DelegateProxy` implemented in `RxSwift3` started breaking in `RxSwift4`. So for those who used `RxSwift3` it wasn't just a pod update but involved loads of changes as well. On following the [RxSwift Git hub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1442) realized that its because of `Swift4` changes which lead to this break.

**Question:**

Now its a very common risk that we take on using all third party frameworks, but with most of the frameworks I used, if broke they would have break a feature or two in app but if I write a complete app in RxSwift and future updates break, finding a replaceable library and replacing it would be a enormous job.

*Here is why?*

For example, if you use Alamofire, usually you will have your own Network layer in app which would expose certain API to app and app quite frankly wont worry about the library used under the hood. So replacing it is quite a easy task. But with RxSwift all asynchronous tools like `delegates`, `blocks`,`notifications` are already wrapped in RxSwift components like `Observables`,`Subjects`,`Units` etc to which we cant write a wrapper of our own and if Current RxSwift version breaks in future update we will be left with no other solution than to literally fix them one by one, as replacing library would mean complete re writing of project.

*I know its a kind of opinion based question*, but the problem is there is no much guiding opinion on web for the same. I would really appreciate, if somebody who used FRP frameworks in their project post the best practice to use them so that dependency on framework will be minimal and allow us to shift to new FRP framework easily in future.

**EDIT:**

The mention of Alamofire above is just to show how easy it is to wrap other frameworks that we use in our app only and has nothing to do with RxSwift in itself. So please don't get carried away by that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short opinion-based answer is that it is safe enough starting from Swift3 because backwards-compatibility is guaranteed starting from Swift3 onwards. I use RxSwift and a bunch of derived frameworks (RxCoreData, RxCloudKit, RxGesture, RxCoreMotion and RaspSwift) extensively for about a year now, never encountered anything particularly troublesome. But then again, you mentioned some frameworks which I did not use that gave compatibility troubles. So apparently there might be unpleasant surprises, which are usually fixed quick enough by the open-source community.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable opinion. I appreciate that hence +1. But do u know any best practice that I can follow/use so that if needed to shift from one FRP to other framework transition changes would be minimal. Like Observable in RxSwift might not be compatible with Observable in Reactive Cocoa. So one approach would be wrap these components in a custom class of my own so when I change to other FRP all I need to change is these custom wrappers. But I think thats hell lot of work

Comment: I would stick with RxSwift only, and that's why:
* ReactiveCocoa itself was inspired by the original Rx back in the day
* RxSwift is a direct port of original Rx, made once Swift language was introduced
* Swift version of ReactiveCocoa is quite different from the old one
* Rx is ported to many languages and platforms, which makes maintenance easier, especially if you develop for more than one platform
* and perhaps most importantly, Rx is recently made compatible to ReactiveStreams which is designed to ensure compatibility of multiple reactive platforms, such as Rx, Akka, Vert.X, etc.

Comment: Hmmm So you believe using RxSwift will not run into situation where I might need to change to different FRP so thinking of custom wrappers n all to minimize the dependency on RxSwift isn't really needed correct ?

Comment: Am concerned because we are writing a reusable components and we don't want them to break or be incompatible state because of underlying RxSwift or any other FRP frameworks

Comment: ReactiveStreams is your custom wrapper now ;) It is designed by providers of different FRP platforms to ensure interoperability with each other.

Comment: ohhhh nice. Lemme have a look. Ill accept your answer in a while, keeping it open just because I wanna know others opinion. But I'll accept your answer in a while (BY EOD of my time :) ) Once again thanks a lot for taking time to answer and helping me out